# Button event is not working by placing it over the image in a nivo image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, nivo-slider

I am using jquery nivo slider plugin. [Nivo slider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/) . In the demo provided had the html caption( single image along html caption ) . I try to add a button instead of html caption . By clicking the button some event will be trigger . The html caption for a image were placed already using this way

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/toystory.jpg "}}" alt="" />
<a href="#">
    <img title="This is an example of a caption " src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/up.jpg "}}" alt="" />
</a>
<img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/walle.jpg "}}" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
<img title="htmlcaption" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/nemo.jpg "}}" alt="" />
```

I try to place  inside the div , but it is not visible in the front end . so I try to place the  under the title attribute of the image tag . This shows the button in the front end page. The following html to add a button to image.

```
<img title="<button id='adbtn'>hello</button>" src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/walle.jpg "}}" alt="" />
```

This image tag is placed in the div having id slider. I can able to view the button in the front end. A click event for the id provided to the button using jquery is not working . It shows *undefined* in the console. I added following Jquery code in header.phtml file

```
jQuery('#adbtn').click(function(){alert('hello btn');});
```

Actually I am using this plugin in magento to have home page slider . Any other ways to implement the button action to the slider is also helped to overcome this problem .  Suggest me some ideas will really help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you click on button .is it showing the message as JQuery not defined ?

Comment: Sizzle, jQuery's selector engine won't find the button this way since it's not looking for HTML elements inside attribute values.

Comment: Nope @PradeepSanku is doesn't show jQuery is not defined ..

Comment: @MarcellFülöp but plugin already use this approach to show html caption . So i tried this way ,but it doesn't sounds good .